# ¿Como comparar los elementos de un array de objetos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar ya que tengo dos dificultades en mi array de objetos.

Mi problema numero uno es que quiero colocar el símbolo de % a uno de los elementos de mi arreglo de objetos y si este es nulo no mostrar el símbolo de porcentaje.

Mi segundo problema es si se pueden hacer un poco mas dinámicos los inicializadores de el objeto ya que trabajo con columnas dinámicas y estos los coloco entre comillas ya que tienen espacios.

Aquí coloco mi código de mi arreglo de objetos espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias.

```js
var fila_actualizada =
                        {
                            "id_persona": id_persona,  //Mis inicializadores de objetos estan entre comillas esto es para el segundo problema     
                            "Sucursal": Sucursal,
                            "Nombre": Nombre,
                           //Aqui le coloco el simbolo de porcentaje pero cuando no ingreso ningun valor mi grid(jqxgrid) lo muestra y no quiero mostrarlo si no contiene algun valor.
                            "Total Pago %": "% " + $("#txtTotal_Pago_porcentaje").val(),
                            "Total Pago $": "$ " + $("#txtTotal_Pago_pesos").val()

                        };
```

Comment: Haz una funcion que retorne el objeto base y si pago no es nulo agrega las propiedades extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tu primer problema podrías usar el método `.length` de un string que devuelve la cantidad de caracteres que tiene, entonces con eso podrías comprobar de que no esté vacío.

En cuanto a tu segundo problema, podrías escribir las `key` del objeto como un nombre único y luego, al utilizarlo lo llamás por su `key` correspondiente.

```js
var fila_actualizada =
  {
      "id_persona": id_persona,     
      "sucursal": Sucursal,
      "nombre": Nombre,
     //Aqui le coloco el simbolo de porcentaje pero cuando no ingreso ningun valor mi grid(jqxgrid) lo muestra y no quiero mostrarlo si no contiene algun valor.
      "total_pago_porcentaje": $("#txtTotal_BonoPorcentaje").val().length ? ($("#txtTotal_BonoPorcentaje").val() + '%') : '',
      "total_pago_pesos": "$ " + $("#txtTotal_BonoPesos").val()
  };
  
// accedo al total de pago en porcentaje
console.log(fila_actualizada.total_pago_porcentaje);
```

Comment: Hola @Kleith muchas gracias estaba investigando y no encontraba como solucionarlo pero me has ayudado mucho funciona de maravilla.